# A word for "somebody who is sponsored"? Sponsee?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means "somebody who is sponsored"?

E.g. if I sponsor somebody, that person is my ______?

Google results for [sponsee](https://www.google.com/search?q=sponsee) have scattered definitions in unreliable sources, so it does not appear that is a real word. I'm looking for something similar, a single word, preferably American English.

The specific context is a social group membership application where new members must be sponsored (as in [definition 2, here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sponsor) - *"one who assumes responsibility for some other person or thing"*) by existing members. I am looking for a single word to describe the target of such a sponsorship.